# Why does Facebook Connect for iPhone login dialogue need a time delay?

Tags: iphone, facebook

I'm new to iPhone programming and stumbled upon an answer to a question, but I was hoping someone could tell me why.

I'm using Facebook Connect in the app.  Since my app requires a login, I was calling the login dialog programmatically rather than with a button.  I am using the SDK example approved code:

```
FBLoginDialog* dialog = [[[FBLoginDialog alloc] init] autorelease];
[dialog show];
```

I'm working with a View-Based App template in Xcode.

Initially I had this placed inside a custom routine I called fbLogin.  But when I put:

```
[self fbLogin];
```

inside viewDidLoad, nothing would happen.  The routine would get called (I slapped an alert in there just to make sure) but the login dialog never appeared.  Instead, if I put this inside viewDidLoad:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(fbLogin) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

Then it worked perfectly.  Anyone know why viewDidLoad is too early to initiate the FBLogin dialog?  I'm fine with the slight delay, but I'm curious.

Thanks.

So there's the solution

Answer (score 0):

When do you create your FBSession object?

If you try to launch the dialog before your FBSession is created, this would fail.

Look at what happens in the five seconds after you kick off your timer. If creating the session is one of these things, that's your answer.

Here's how I do it in ViewDidLoad, I do not need a timer or any weirdness.

//

_session = [[FBSession sessionForApplication:@"2754b468daf788dd8c0849e261798616" secret:@"cb5c2b89677d570a28c29582290a546c" delegate:self] 
                retain];

```
CGRect buttonFrame = CGRectMake(160.0f, 240.0f, 60, 37);


if ( [_session resume] == NO)
{
    FBLoginButton* loginButton = [[FBLoginButton alloc]initWithFrame:buttonFrame];
    [self.view addSubview: loginButton];
}
```

//

Note that if you do not specify a frame for the button and just call init, it does not work.
Also, I have an extra bit of code to check if we can resume from the session, which stores all the keys etc as defaults.

Comment: The Facebook SDK lists two ways of showing the dialog--yours which uses the button and mine which is programmatically called.  I used mine because the app requires a Facebook connection.

I created a routine I call fbLogin.  It creates the session like your code, then checks the resume call to see if it needs to show the dialog.

The problem is that if I put [self fbLogin]; inside the viewDidLoad routine, nothing happens.  I'm always creating the session prior to calling the dialog, so I'm trying to figure out why the delay makes it work.